# Helly's theorem in other areas of mathematics

Tags: convex-geometry

Are there some outstanding results using some version of Helly's theorem in a totally different area (whatever that means) than convex geometry?

Comment: The Helly property for cat(0) cube complexes is used in geometric group theory

Comment: Supplementing Benjamin's comment: Ivanov, Sergei. "On Helly's theorem in geodesic spaces." [arXiv:1401.6654](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6654) (2014).

Comment: Is [Helly's selection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_selection_theorem) an infinite dimensional version of this?  Same guy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Applications of Helly's theorem to linear programming are discussed
  in this [thesis](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/pubs/ninathesis.pdf).
- Then there are applications to the theory of approximation of
  continuous functions by polynomials ([Chebyshev
  approximation](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~khudian/Etudes/Algebra/chebysh2.pdf)).
- [Robotics](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~anguyen/papers/disconnection.pdf) (the discovery of an obstacle-avoiding path) makes use of Helly's theorem.
- [Analysis of Incomplete Data and an Intrinsic-Dimension Helly Theorem](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~jgao/paper/clustering_lines.pdf) discusses an application in the context of pattern recognition.
- [A Wavelet Approximation to the Helmholtz Equation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X99964065) relies on Helly's theorem.
- Finally, an application to the social sciences appears in the proof of the 
  [Agreeable Society Theorem.](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3245v1)

Answer (score 6):

The famous Krasnoselsky criteria for star-shaped regions is based on Helly theorem. It is important in embedding theorems for Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Helly's theorem plays a role in economics theory and in game theory
(noncooperative games):

> - Fuchs-Seliger, Susanne. "An application of Helly's theorem to preference-generated choice correspondences." *International Economic Review* (1984): 71-77.
>     ([Jstor link](http://econpapers.repec.org/article/ieriecrev/v_3a25_3ay_3a1984_3ai_3a1_3ap_3a71-77.htm).)
> - Raghavan, T. E. S. "Zero-sum two-person games." *Handbook of Game Theory* 2 (1994): 735-768. ([PDF download](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/T_Raghavan/publication/223809491_Chapter_44_Non-zero-sum_two-person_games/links/54107d4c0cf2f2b29a410e0a.pdf).)